# Annihilation of pairs $e^{+}$ and $e^{-}$ and photon production

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, antimatter

In the annihilation of pairs  $e^{+}$ and $e^{-}$, two gamma photons are formed. Is the reverse process, ie, if we collide two photons, will they form an electron  and positron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse process to electron-positron annihilation is called pair production. It is the time reversal of pair annihilation and is a perfectly viable process with exactly the same amplitude as for annihilation. Note that this is so because quantum electrodynamics is symmetric under time reversal.

Why two photons and not one are produced (or needed) for pair annihilation ( or production) is an important question. This is due to the fact that both energy and momentum are conserved at each interaction vertex and a single photon cannot do the both the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The production of electron/positron pair is not the reversal of annihilation.  To do this, you need a photon of greater than 1.02 MeV.  When that passes a massive object, there is a possibility that it will split into a positron and electron.

The problem with the reverse process is that the resultant photons are 0.51 MeV each.  If you were to collide them and they would produce a pair, that pair would have no energy and would immediately annihilate back into 2 photons.

Comment: i didn't get why this is not the reversal of annihilation.. when pair annihilation takes place, photons on not less than 1.022 MeV are generated, with each having at least 0.511 MeV.. The Feynman diagram for one is virtually the time reversal of the other and the amplitude is also same(QED is invariant under time reversal)..also i dint get your argument regarding why photons of 0.51 MeV each will have "no energy and will annihilate back to 2 photons"

Comment: Remember that the Feynman diagram is only a representation of the math behind the physics, not the physics itself.  I have not seen any papers (they could exist and if they do I would love to read them) that show that the reverse physical process works.  However, we have seen the pair production with 1.02 MeV photons.